# How to substitute text before and/or after a variable string?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to change text in a file before and after non-fixed strings.
I'll show an example:

```
this-is-cat-really-weird  
this-is-dog-really-weird  

there-is-cat-really-weird  
there-is-dog-really-weird  

that-is-cat-really-weird  
that-is-dog-really-weird
```

I need to write a single instruction to change only the first two lines, as the desired output will be the following:

```
this-is-cat-really-nice  
this-is-dog-really-nice  

there-is-cat-really-weird  
there-is-dog-really-weird  

that-is-cat-really-weird  
that-is-dog-really-weird
```

I've not beeb able to found a suitable solution using awk.
Also, how can I write a working instruction if I have 100+ lines like these that I'd like to change, and these lines could be anywhere in the file?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I don't understand the - updated - question

Answer (score 1):

Use sed with range of lines:

```
$ sed '1,2s/weird/nice/' input.txt
this-is-cat-really-nice  
this-is-dog-really-nice  

there-is-cat-really-weird  
there-is-dog-really-weird  

that-is-cat-really-weird  
that-is-dog-really-weird
```

To match anywhere in the file:

```
$ sed '/this-is-cat-really/{s/weird/nice/;N;s/weird/nice/}' input.txt 
this-is-cat-really-nice  
this-is-dog-really-nice  

there-is-cat-really-weird  
there-is-dog-really-weird  

that-is-cat-really-weird  
that-is-dog-really-weird  

this-is-cat-really-nice  
this-is-dog-really-nice
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check the update in the end of the question (I forgot to write it earlier).

Comment: @RodrigoAndresNavaLara  After the edit, your question asks two different things. I've edited the answer, but for future please remember this is not proper - only one question per post; otherwise this makes the post unclear and it will be closed